# Unable to print a specific string in HTML using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, xss

Im facing a difficulty in rendering this string into html using javaScript

```js
"<img onerror='window.document.body.innerHTML = \"<h1>XSS</h1>\";' src=''> "
```

When i try rendering it into an element in HTML using JavaScript the only output i get is **XSS** on a plain page

Please suggest a way i could render this into html as plain text.

Comment: Why would you replace the entire page when the image fails?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's hard to figure out exactly what's going wrong since we can't see how you're rendering this into HTML. Can you please add how you're using that string in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Node.textContent` instead of Node.innerHTML:

```
"<img onerror='window.document.body.textContent = \"<h1>XSS</h1>\";' src=''> "
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the whole html code to be shown as text then use `innerText` or `textContent` as they will not attempt to render html code.

```
//using template literals ` (backtick) to help not need escaping quotes
document.body.innerText = `<img onerror="window.document.body.innerHTML ='<h1>XSS</h1>';" src=''>`
```

Otherwise if you want the `<h1>` part to show as text then use the same `innerText` / `textContent` but on the inline js code

```
<img onerror="window.document.body.innerText ='<h1>XSS</h1>';" src=''>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.innerText` if you want to skip the html code from render:

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerText = "<h1>XSS</h1>";
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is Cross-site scripting (XSS) which is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side scripts into web pages viewed by other users.
you have to sanitize the string by using below function

```js
String.prototype.escape = function() {
    var tagsToReplace = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
    };
    return this.replace(/[&<>]/g, function(tag) {
        return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
    });
};
```

here is the list of xss vulnerability  https://www.vulnerability-lab.com/resources/documents/531.txt